# How to update the daily local notification message in iOS 10?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, unusernotificationcenter

I'm trying to find out how to update the message in the local notifications when it is repeated daily.

Currently I have the following code in my AppDelegate:

```
func scheduler(at date: Date, numOfNotes: Int)
{
    let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)

    let components = calendar.dateComponents(in: .current, from: date)

    let newComponents = DateComponents(calendar: calendar, timeZone: .current, hour: components.hour, minute: components.minute)

    let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: newComponents, repeats: true)

    content.badge = numOfNotes as NSNumber

    content.body = "REMINDER: " + String(numOfNotes) + " needs to be looked at!"

    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()

    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "reminderNotification", content: content, trigger: trigger)

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) {(error) in

    }
}
```

I am storing `numOfNotes` in `UserDefaults`. I have a `UISwitch` in my `UITableViewCell`, that upon being switched on calls the `scheduler` function like so:

```
func remindMeSwitch(_ remindMeSwitch: UISwitch)
{   
    numOfNotes = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "Notes")

    let delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate

    delegate?.scheduler(at: time, numOfNotes: numOfNotes)
}
```

However, when setting the `repeats` parameter to `true` to have the notification repeat daily at the specified time, `numOfNotes` is only called once, which is when I toggle the `UISwitch` on.

How can I set the notification to alert daily but still be able to update the notification message as needed?

Thanks.

Comment: It would seems that you'd need to schedule individual non-repeating notifications with appropriate messages to achieve this.

Comment: @Losiowaty, i'd suspect that was the case but i was hoping to not have to re-schedule every time the count changes

Comment: You can try adding a notification service app extension, but I'm not sure if it is called for local notifications. Also its available only from iOS 10.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you don't have any possibility to change Local Notifications.
Only one way - delete/cancel the old notification and create the new notification. But you can use a copy function.

For example, if you want to change the notification's content:

```
// create new content (based on old)
if let content = notificationRequest.content.mutableCopy() as? UNMutableNotificationContent {
    // any changes    
    content.title = "your new content's title"
    // create new notification
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: notificationRequest.identifier, content: content, trigger: notificationRequest.trigger)
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request)
}
```